# Split string into multiple lines

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, string, split, substring

I have a long string of comments that I'd like to split into multiple lines.

It's currently displayed as `<%= Html.Encode(item.important_notes) %>`
I've played with using `.Substring` to split it, but can't figure out how to prevent it from splitting in the middle of a word.  Instead of characters 1-100 on line 1 and 101-200 on line 2, I'd like to do something like character 1 through the last space before character 100 on line one.  That character through the last space before the next 100 characters on line 2, etc.

What is the best way to do this?

EDIT: using ASP.NET-MVC

Comment: Care to name a programming language? Are you talking about JSP here?

Comment: Language would be asp.net mvc by the looks of it...

Comment: Is it not possible to let your html stylesheet dictate the width of the text?

Comment: @Michael-This is going into a cell in a DataTables.net jquery plugin table. I can manually set the width of the column which does the trick, however then the width of each column must be manually set. I started to do this, but I'd like for the other columns to format based on their contents.  However, when autoformatting the Comments column is putting 2-3 words in a line and using a ton of lines making cell very tall and narrow.  Trying to find a work-around, I thought that separating into a few lines with `<nobr></nobr>` around them would do the trick.

Comment: You can use &nbsp; instead avoid splitting (non-breaking whitespace).

Comment: @queen3 - The comments are user-entered.  I'm just displaying them.  I could wrap the whole thing with <nobr></nobr> but I don't want the entire comment to be on one line if they've used the entire 300 characters allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a combination of substring and lastindexof.  You get the last index of combined with a number to get the first space after your breakpoint.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (base.Length > 100)
{
   if (!base.Contains(" ")) { break;
   sb.Append(base.Substring(0, base.Substring(0, 100).LastIndexOf(" ")));
   //code to trim down base
   sb.Append(/*newline*/);
}
sb.Append(base);
```

Written adhoc, but you get the idea.

Comment: I didn't do it exactly this way, but a combo of Substring and LastIndexOf did the trick.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to speak specifically to your issue, I would suggest you look into regular expressions. Regular expressions are able to handle complex text patterns with ease. You may have a split function available to you that takes just such a regular expression and returns an array of Strings.